# Python - Trying to make a questionaire pulling answers from a DB

Tags: python, sql

```
# insertions with SQL

# importing module
import sqlite3

# connecting to the database 
conn = sqlite3.connect("illness.db")

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS illnesses(illnessID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, illness VARCHAR(30), illnessinfo VARCHAR(50)") 
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symptoms(symptomID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, symptom VARCHAR(50)")

def data_entry():
c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses VALUES(,'Flu','Influenza - Common Cold.')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses VALUES(,'Acne','Skin Condition')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses VALUES(,'Alcohol Misuse','Mega Hangover')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms VALUES(,'Headache')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms VALUES(,'Spots')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms VALUES(,'Breathing problems')")
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()

create_table()
data_entry()
```

As per the title this is what i'm running on for a database (Using LiClipse) however it just doesn't work and i'm not sure why (As a note: I looked at youtube video's to try and sort this out and i'm just really new to python and not sure how to really go about doing this at all. 
On top of this i'm not even sure if using Liclipse is the best option at all. it was just suggested by a friend...

Comment: can you provide the error also for now  what i see is you create the `c = conn.cursor()` out side the methods and using that inside of methods.

Comment: It says Traceback,  main(),  globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module),     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script, exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc), create_table(), syntax error

Comment: create_table() method query you have syntax errors end of the qery string there should be ')'  `    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS illnesses(illnessID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, illness VARCHAR(30), illnessinfo VARCHAR(50))")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symptoms(symptomID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, symptom VARCHAR(50))")`

Comment: warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\Owner\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.1.201802272029\pysrc\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 14296)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.1.201802272029\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1621, in <module>
    main()    

And a host of other errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Queries  in create_table() data_entry() methods are incorrect

I cannot figure out whether you closing the cursor and the connection inside the `data_entry` method or out side because your indentation is not properly done with the provided code so i put those at the below  and or you can close them inside `data_entry` method

```
# insertions with SQL

# importing module
import sqlite3

# connecting to the database 
conn = sqlite3.connect("illness.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS illnesses(illnessID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, illness VARCHAR(30), illnessinfo VARCHAR(50))")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symptoms(symptomID INTAGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, symptom VARCHAR(50))")

def data_entry():

    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(123,'Flu','Influenza - Common Cold.')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(1234,'Acne','Skin Condition')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(345,'Alcohol Misuse','Mega Hangover')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(567,'Headache')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(234,'Spots')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(789,'Breathing problems')")


create_table()
data_entry()

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

this one also should work

```
def data_entry():

    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(123,'Flu','Influenza - Common Cold.')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(1234,'Acne','Skin Condition')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(345,'Alcohol Misuse','Mega Hangover')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(567,'Headache')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(234,'Spots')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms (symptomID,symptom) VALUES(789,'Breathing problems')")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: So the primary key isn't valid due to you adding a value to it:

`code: File "C:\Users\Owner\eclipse-workspace\Diss\db.py", line 31, in <module>
    data_entry()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\eclipse-workspace\Diss\db.py", line 22, in data_entry
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses(illnessID, illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(1,'Flu','Influenza - Common Cold.')")
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: illnesses.illnessID`

Comment: that is because once  you ran the method it added the values when you run again the ID values are duplicated  so it violates the primary key constraints

Comment: this is and additional info You can use use One method with parameters and assign that method to the query string so that you don't have to repeate the query strings ex:  `def insertIllness(record):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO illnesses( illness , illnessinfo) VALUES(?,?)",record)
`  and the nyou can call this method as `insertIllness(['Acne','Skin Condition'])`  going through sqlite documentation and python sqlite tutorials you can achieve this practices. cheers